# Express.js: how to bypass Everyauth for certain routes?

Tags: node.js, express, everyauth

I'm writing an application based on Express.js, while using Everyauth for authentication.

To initialize everyauth, I use:

```
app.use(everyauth.middleware());
```

I'd like to **bypass authentication** for certain routes.
Specifically, I noticed findUserById is called for every request, and I'd like to skip it for certain routes (e.g. no authentication for /getImage).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the `everyauth.middleware()` callback manually.

```
var auth = everyauth.middleware();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (shouldAuthRequest(req)) {
    // call auth, as if it was part of the route
    auth(req, res, next);
  } else {
    // ignore auth
    next();
  }
});
```

This is nothing but a wrapped middleware.

Comment: Thanks Tharabas. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. It says auth() is not a function. I tried calling everyauth.middleware() directly instead, but it doesn't call next(), and therefore it doesn't handle any request.

Answer (score 1):

As of 0.4.5, `everyauth.middleware` must be called with Express's `app` object. You can therefore create a wrapped middleware this way:

```
var my_auth_middleware = function(app) {
  var auth = everyauth.middleware(app);
  // a custom middleware wrapping everyauth
  var middleware = function(req, res, next) {
    if (shouldAuthRequest(req)) {
      // go through the everyauth middleware
      auth(req, res, next);
    } else {
      // bypass everyauth
      next();
    }
  };
  // these allow the middleware to be "mounted" by Express
  middleware.set = true;
  middleware.handle = middleware;
  middleware.emit = auth.emit;
  // return our custom middleware
  return middleware;
};
```

and then add your wrapped middleware to the stack with

```
app.use(my_auth_middleware(app));
```

Comment: kiddorails, I'm using the [#express3](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/tree/express3) branch of everyauth, and the source of the `everyauth.middleware` method is [here](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/blob/express3/index.js#L24-52).  I'm not sure how the `app` object is used, but both READMEs of the `master` and `express3` branches suggest that it should be passed to `everyauth.middleware`